# Convert and check if struct IList contains nullable int. c#

Tags: c#, struct, int, nullable, typeconverter

I have a struct named `CheckedNumber`. This type is used in a property:

```
`public IList<CheckedNumber> CheckedNumbers { get { return this._checkedNumbers; } }`
```

...to keep a list of numbers.

I have another property:

```
`public int? TheNumber { get { return this._theNumber; } }`
```

...and want to check if its value exists in the `CheckedNumbers` list.

this:

```
if (this.CheckedNumbers.Contains(this.TheNumber)) { //... }
```

gives error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?' to 'ProjectName.Models.CheckedNumber'
```

How could I convert int? to my struct type?

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you mean. Does `CheckedNumber` *implement* `IList`? (It would be odd for a struct to implement that...) Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now the question is *slightly* clearer - but fundamentally, you're asking whether a list of `CheckedNumber` values contains a particular `int?` value. That makes no sense, as an `int?` *isn't* a `CheckedNumber` - it's like asking whether a `List<Fruit>` contains a car.

If *part* or your `CheckedNumber` struct is an `int?`, you might want:

```
if (CheckedNumbers.Any(x => x.SomeProperty == TheNumber))
```

Alternatively, you *might* want:

```
if (CheckedNumbers.Contains(new CheckedNumber(TheNumber)))
```

Otherwise, you'll have to clarify the question further.

Comment: If I'd like to add values that has ´int?´ type to the CheckedNumbers list. How should that be done? CheckedNumbers.Add(...)

Comment: @user1121487: Well you'll need to be able to convert an `int?` to ` CheckedNumber`. Do you understand that an `IList<CheckedNumber>` can *only* hold values of type `CheckedNumber`?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. But it's not clear to me how to convert these types.

Comment: @user1121487: If it's not clear to *you*, when you know what's in `CheckedNumber`, I'm not sure how you expect it to be clear to *us*, when you haven't told us anything about `CheckedNumber` other than that it's a struct. It sounds like you probably want to ask a new question, after reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: CheckedNumber struct only contain one field: ´public int? Number;´

Comment: @user1121487: `GuessedNumber`? Not `CheckedNumber`? Why would you bother with a struct which is exactly equivalent to `int?`? Why not just use `int?` to start with? And why would you use a public field, making it a *mutable* struct?

Comment: Misstyped. Can't tell why, probably cause it's more neater with a custom type? This is a project made by someone else, I'm trying to modify it.

Comment: @user1121487: Well maybe you should talk to them about it... it appears to be anything *but* neat...

Answer (score 0):

Let `CheckedNumber` implement `IEquatable<CheckedNumber>`. The `Contains` method of your list can then use this method to find list items.

```
public struct CheckedNumber : IEquatable<CheckedNumber>
{
    public CheckedNumber(int? number)
    {
        _value = number;
    }

    private int? _value;
    public int? Value { get { return _value; } }

    public bool Equals(CheckedNumber other)
    {
        return _value == other._value;
    }
}
```

Now you can do your check by converting the `int?` to a `CheckedNumber`

```
if (this.CheckedNumbers.Contains(new CheckedNumber(this.TheNumber))) {
    //...
}
```